# copy small files in parallel from remote servers

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scp, gnu-parallel

I have to copy lots of files (around 2000 file and each file size around 5MB) from remote servers on a local box so I usually run below command on my local box terminal to copy files:

```
scp goldy@machineA:/process/snap/20180418/* /data/files/
```

Is there any way to copy those files in parallel from remote servers using gnu-parallel or anything else? I mean something like copy 5 files in parallel instead of doing everything one by one.

**Note:** below is my file names on remote servers.

```
abc_proc_1_log.data
abc_proc_2_log.data
abc_proc_3_log.data
abc_proc_4_log.data
...
abc_proc_2000_log.data
```

Comment: Split up the list of files, and issue a separate `scp` command for each set.

Comment: You would still use the same network channel for transferring files. Parallel local processes would not make it faster. Unless it is the encryption /decryption that is the bottleneck.

Comment: There is no harm in trying out and I have 10GB network pipe so wanted to see if this makes any difference.

Comment: Whether or not multiple scp processes improve bandwidth depends on how quickly your TCP implementation is able to ramp up its window size. But, it is unlikely to be able to ramp up quickly enough to allow maximal throughput.

Comment: @user1950349, Do you have GNU parallel installed at your remote `machineA`?

Comment: On remote `machineA` it's not installed but on my localbox where I am copying files it is installed. I can get it installed though. But why it needs to be installed on remote `machineA`? Also I need to run this command from local box only.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: `scp` has a very high per-file overhead. Compare it to something better for smaller files like a single tar stream:  `ssh goldy@machineA "tar c /process/snap/20180418/*" | tar x -C /data/files`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ssh goldy@machineA 'ls -1 /process/snap/20180418/*' \
| parallel -j5 'scp goldy@machineA:{} /data/files/{}'
```

---

- `ssh goldy@machineA 'ls -1 /process/snap/20180418/*'` - get filename list from the remote machine beforehand
- `parallel -j5 ...` - run up to 5 jobs in parralel

Comment: Given that the files are 5 MB and running 5 in parallel is probably too little: A lot of time will be spent on simply logging in, so increasing 5 will probably be a good idea.

Comment: I tried your above suggestion but it looks like something is off with scp command you have inside parallel. It is trying to find files in this format `scp: /process/snap/20180418//process/snap/20180418/abc_monthly_1000_log.data: No such file or directory` but in general it should be `/process/snap/20180418/abc_monthly_1000_log.data`. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: @user1950349, that's right, that was a path issue. See my update

Comment: Thats the first thing I tried but it failed again with this error message `/data/files//process/snap/20180418/abc_monthly_1000_log.data: No such file or directory`. Now it is mixed with destination directory path somehow

Comment: I think instead of this `/data/files/{}`, it should be `/data/files/`. What do you think?

Comment: The provided command is attempting to mirror the file hierarchy. You seem to want all the files delivered into a single directory. If that is what you want, `/data/files/` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is described in the man page for GNU Parallel (`man parallel`):
https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Parallelizing-rsync

```
seq -w 0 99 | parallel rsync -Havessh fooserver:src/*{}.png destdir/
```

But with that small files, you probably want to add `-j100 --delay 0.01`. The delay should make sure that sshd is not overwhelmed.